# fetching data from firebase not working Simulator crash "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16e607fe0)"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

My Swift code does not fetch the data from firebase loggin user.

In the `LoginForiOSApp` file it gives the error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16e607fe0)
```

The code from the `LoginForiOSApp` file is

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct LoginForiOS: App {
    init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

The login fetch code is

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

struct LoginView: View {
    //MARK: User Details
    @State var emailID: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    //MARK: View Properties
    @State var createAccount: Bool = false
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State var isLoading: Bool = false
    //MARK: User Defaulds
    @AppStorage("user_profile_url") var profileURL: URL?
    @AppStorage("user_name") var userNameStored: String = ""
    @AppStorage("user_UID") var userUID: String = ""
    @AppStorage("Log_status") var logStatus: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            Text("Lets Sign you in")
                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                .hAlign(.leading)
            
            Text("Welcome Back,\nYou have been missed")
                .font(.title3)
                .hAlign(.leading)
            
            VStack(spacing: 12){
                TextField("Email", text: $emailID)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .padding(.top,5)
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .border(1, .gray.opacity(0.5))
                
                Button("Reset password", action: resetPassword)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .tint(.black)
                    .hAlign(.trailing)
                
                Button (action: loginUser) {
                    //MARK: Login Button
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .hAlign(.center)
                        .fillView(.black)
                }
                .padding(.top,10)
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
            }
            
            //MARK: Register Button
            HStack{
                Text("Don't have an account?")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
                Button("Register Now"){
                    createAccount.toggle()
                }
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .font(.callout)
            .vhAlign(.bottom)
        }
        .vhAlign(.top)
        .padding(15)
        .overlay(content: {
            LoadingView(show: $isLoading)
        })
        //MARK: Register View VIA Sheets
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $createAccount) {
            RegisterView()
        }
        //MARK: Displaying Alert
        .alert(errorMessage, isPresented: $showError, actions: {})
    }
    
    func loginUser(){
        isLoading = true
        closeKeyboard()
        Task{
            do{
                // With the help of Swift Concurrency Auth can be done with Single Line
                try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailID, password: password)
                print("User Found")
                try await fetchUser()
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: If User if Found then Fetching User Data From Firestore
    func fetchUser()async throws{
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
        let user = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userID).getDocument(as: User.self)
        //MARK: UI Updating Must Be Run On Main Thread
        await MainActor.run(body: {
            // Setting UserDefaults data and Changing App's Auth Status
            userUID = userID
            userNameStored = user.username
            profileURL = user.userProfileURL
            logStatus = true
        })
    }
    
    func resetPassword(){
        Task{
            do{
                // With the help of Swift Concurrency Auth can be done with Single Line
                try await Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: emailID)
                print("Link Sent")
            }catch{
            }
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Displaying Errors VIA Alert
    func setError(_ error: Error)async{
        //MARK: UI Must be Updated on Main Thread
        await MainActor.run(body: {
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            showError.toggle()
            isLoading = false
        })
    }
    
    struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

I builded the app and i just have to wait and then he gives the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16e607fe0)"

Comment: Is there an error message in console when it crashes? Does it show a specific line?

Comment: You need to step through your code and find out at what line this crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the code in `fetchUser()` as:

```
func fetchBook(documentId: String) async throws{
  guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{return}
  let user = try await Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(userID)
       
  do{ 
  try user.getDocument(as: User.self) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let User):
      self.User = User
      logStatus = true
    case .failure(let error):
      // A User value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
      print("Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
 } catch let error as NSError {
     print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
  }
}
```

DO NOT MAP YOUR DOCUMENTS MANUALLY. USE CODABLE INSTEAD.

While it might seem straightforward and easy to implement, this code is fragile, hard to maintain, and error-prone. As you can see, we’re making assumptions about the data types of the document fields .

User class will look something like this:

```
public struct User: Codable {

    let username: String
    let userProfileURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case username
        case userProfileURL
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add an explenation why you think this would help?

Comment: Done and structured as so that we can catch error as well if there is any. @burnsi
Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: he. I have tried it but it doesn't work. it still gives the error but I'm not entirely sure that it is an error it could also be a simulator error it happends when I build the app and then it just happens

Comment: can you put whole code in try catch and send the error log @ZIYAXSERVERS

Comment: @Akrosh Teotia that is the whole code (do you mean the whole project) and i don't know where to find the error log

Comment: I think it has something to do with ram memory

Comment: @ZIYAXSERVERS I have added try catch block. Please use this updated code then share the log. It will prevent build from crashing.

Comment: he gives this error "Value of type 'LoginView' has no member 'User'" what do i need to add

Comment: This explain a lot. You don't have defined User Class and you are tying to access in your main code. I am updating the code and adding User class.